# Continuous coloring of fractal

Tags: opengl, fractals

I'm trying to visualize Mandelbrot set with OpenGL and have found very strange behaviour when it comes to smooth coloring.

Let's assume, for the current complex value`C`, algorithm have escaped after `n` iterations when `Z` had been proven to be more than 2.

I programmed coloring part like this:

```
if(n==maxIterations){
   color=0.0; //0.0 is black in OpenGL when put to each channel of RGB 
              //Points in M-brot set are colored black.
} else {
   color = (n + 1 - log(log(abs(Z)))/log(2.0) )/maxIterations; 
   //continuous coloring algorithm, color is between 0.0 and 1.0
   //Points outside M-brot set are colored depending of their absolute value,
   //from brightest near the edge of set to darkest far away from set.
}
glColor3f(color ,color ,color );
//OpenGL-command for making RGB-color from three channel values.
```

The problem is, this just don't work well. Some smoothing is noticable, but it's not perfect.

But when I add two additional iterations (just found this somewhere without explanation)

```
Z=Z*Z+C; 
n++;
```

in the "else"-branch before calculating a color, the picture comes out to be absolutely, gracefully smooth.

Why does this happen? Why do we need to place additional iterations in coloring part *after* checking the point to be in set?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What language is that? I wonder since it seems to have an abs()-function that handles complex numbers.

Comment: This is Visual C++. Code was written using Visual C++'s <complex> class. Check it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0352zzhd.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not actually certain, but I'm *guessing* it has something to do with the fact that the log of the log of a number (`log(log(n))`) is somewhat of an unstable thing for "small" numbers `n`, where "small" in this case means something close to 2.  If your `Z` has just escaped, it's close to 2.  If you continue to iterate, you get (quickly) further and further from 2, and `log(log(abs(Z)))` stabilizes, thus giving you a more predictable value... which, then, gives you smoother values.

Example data, arbitrarily chosen:

```
 n            Z.real            Z.imag         |Z|  status color
-- ----------------- ----------------- ----------- ------- -----
 0             -0.74              -0.2    0.766551 bounded [nonsensical]
 1           -0.2324             0.096    0.251447 bounded [nonsensical]
 2       -0.69520624        -0.2446208    0.736988 bounded [nonsensical]
 3    -0.31652761966     0.14012381319    0.346157 bounded [nonsensical]
 4    -0.65944494902    -0.28870611409    0.719874 bounded [nonsensical]
 5    -0.38848357953     0.18077157738    0.428483 bounded [nonsensical]
 6    -0.62175887162    -0.34045357891    0.708867 bounded [nonsensical]
 7    -0.46932454495     0.22336006613    0.519765 bounded [nonsensical]
 8    -0.56962419064    -0.40965672279    0.701634 bounded [nonsensical]
 9    -0.58334691196     0.26670075833    0.641423 bounded [nonsensical]
10     -0.4708356748    -0.51115812757     0.69496 bounded [nonsensical]
11    -0.77959639873     0.28134296385    0.828809 bounded [nonsensical]
12     -0.2113833184    -0.63866792284     0.67274 bounded [nonsensical]
13     -1.1032138084    0.070007489775     1.10543 bounded 0.173185134517425
14     0.47217965836    -0.35446645882    0.590424 bounded [nonsensical]
15    -0.64269284066    -0.53474370285    0.836065 bounded [nonsensical]
16     -0.6128967403     0.48735189882    0.783042 bounded [nonsensical]
17    -0.60186945901    -0.79739278033    0.999041 bounded [nonsensical]
18     -1.0135884004     0.75985272263     1.26678 bounded 0.210802091344997
19    -0.29001471459     -1.7403558114     1.76435 bounded 0.208165835763602
20     -3.6847298156     0.80945758785     3.77259 ESCAPED 0.205910029166315
21      12.182012228     -6.1652650168     13.6533 ESCAPED 0.206137522227716
22      109.65092918     -150.41066764     186.136 ESCAPED 0.20614160700086
23     -10600.782669     -32985.538932     34647.1 ESCAPED 0.20614159039676
24     -975669186.18       699345058.7 1.20042e+09 ESCAPED 0.206141590396481
25  4.6284684972e+17 -1.3646588486e+18 1.44101e+18 ESCAPED 0.206141590396481
26 -1.6480665667e+36  -1.263256098e+36 2.07652e+36 ESCAPED 0.206141590396481
```

Notice how much the color value is still fluctuating at n in [20,22], getting stable at n=23, and consistent from n=24 onward.  And notice that the Z values there are WAY outside the circle of radius 2 that bounds the Mandelbrot set.

I haven't actually done enough of the math to be sure that this is actually a solid explanation, but that would be my guess.

Comment: I should point out that I'm not actually certain that this is what does it.  Having checked some other numbers, the part I said about the stabilization from continued iterations is accurate, but the difference between, say, 1st-escape values of one point, and 1st-escape values of another, nearby point, didn't seem to be greater than the difference between, say, 5-iterations-past-escape values.  But maybe I was just using points that happened to evaluate very similarly?  I'd have to explore it in much more depth to be certain.

Answer (score 4):

AS I just made the same program and as good mathematician I'll explain it why, hope it would be clear.

If let say the sequence with seed C has escaped after k iterations.

Since the function it self is defined as Limit as the iterations go to infinity it is not that good the get something close to k. Here is why.

As we know that after 2 the sequence goes infinity let's consider some iteration T where z has become enough big. Considered to it C will be insegnificantly small, since normally you look the set in [-2,2] and [-1.5,1.5] for the 2 axis. So on the T+1 iteration z will be ~~ z^2 from the previous and is easy to check that in that case |z| of T+1 will be ~~ |z|^2 of the previous.

Our function is log(|z|)/2^k for the K-th iteration. In the case we are looking at
it is easy to see That on the T+1 iteration it will be ~~
[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/e8ab9446e81684037708209bf8f3a297.gif))</sub>

which is the function at T iteration.

In other words as |z| becomes "significantly" bigger than the seed C the function becomes more and more stable. You DO NOT want to use an iteration close to escaping iteration k, since there actually Z will be close to 2 , and as depending on C it may not be insignificantly small compared to it and so you will not be close to the Limit.

As |C| is near 2 actually on the first escaping iteration you will be a LOT away from the Limit. If on the other hand you choose to make it after |Z|>100 for escaping bound for instance or just take several more iterations you will get quite more stable.

Hope for anyone interested in the question to have answered him good.

Answer (score 3):

For now it seems that "additional iterations" idea has no convincing formulas for it, if not counting the fact it just works.

In one old version of Wikipedia's Mandelbrot article there are lines about Continuous Coloring:

> Second, it is recommended that a few
>   extra iterations are done so that z
>   can grow. If you stop iterating as
>   soon as z escapes, there is the
>   possibility that the smoothing
>   algorithm will not work.

Better than nothing.